# How to retrieve sim detail from android on sms receive

Tags: android, smsmanager

I am working on Sms Receive in android,if the users phone is a dual sim phone how to identify the sim from which SMS is being received,in the uploaded picture the message has been received by sim2, how can I retrieve that info on my message receiver?
[image]

Comment: please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16279210/get-the-imsi-number-or-destination-phone-number-from-incomming-message-sms

Answer (score 1):

Android SDK does not have support for dual sim.
you need to contact your device manufacturer for sdk.