# IBM Worklight - How to get IMSI number from mobile device?

Tags: android, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

We want to get the `IMSI` number for the mobile device in order to find out if the user is registered to use particular application or not.

I did search on the net. It say Worklight is using Cordova. It gives UUID and device name /description but not IMSI number.

I am trying this code here. but the cordova always goes to getfailure. and says Class Not Found. I am using IBM Worklight

```
import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.content.Context;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;



   @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {

        if (action.equals("imeiNumber")) {

            org.json.JSONObject r = new org.json.JSONObject();

            TelephonyManager tManager = (TelephonyManager) cordova.getActivity().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);            

            r.put("imei", "sampleimei");
            r.put("imsi", "sampleimsi123");
            r.put("tmanagerimsi", tManager.getSimSerialNumber());
            r.put("deviceModal", this.getModel() );

            callbackContext.success(r);

            return true;

        } 
        else {

            return false;

        }

    }
```

javascript:

```
function getImei(){
    alert("inside getImei");
    cordova.exec(getSuccess, getFailure, "DeviceDetails", "imeiNumber", []);
}

function getSuccess(data){
    alert(data.imei +" "+data.imsi+" "+data.tmanagerimsi);
}

function getFailure(data){
    alert(data);
    alert(data.imei +" "+data.imsi+" "+data.tmanagerimsi+" "+data.deviceModal);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is what you pasted above the full java file? Because it does not seem complete.

You are missing the class declaration. Usually classes in Java are defined like:

```
public class Dog{
 //stuff
}
```

I do not see this anywhere in your code.

Also, when installing a plugin you need to modify the config.xml to reflect this.

Please review carefully this guide: http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/06_05_Android_-_Adding_native_functionality_to_hybrid_application_with_Apache_Cordova_plugin.pdf

Comment: HI, I am missing the plugin in config.xml, instead of feature, i wrote <plugin> </plugin>

Answer (score 1):

To get the IMSI number, you will need to create a Cordova plug-in in order to access this information which is stored in the device.

See the following training modules how to create a Cordova plug-in in Worklight:

- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#cordova

See the following topics how to get the `IMEI` number, and similarly the `IMSI` number. You will then need to combine the two (Cordova plug-in and native code from the above), to get the data you want:

- [How to get IMEI number in PhoneGap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8742850/how-to-get-imei-number-in-phonegap)
- [Get the IMSI number or destination phone number from incomming message (SMS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16279210/get-the-imsi-number-or-destination-phone-number-from-incomming-message-sms)

Comment: hi, how should i access Telephonymanager in worklight. I created android environment and added Telephony class. Now, I donot know how i should access it in worklight common application.

Comment: Did you read the training modules? You need to create a Cordova plug-in and use Native code to access it.

Comment: hi, i created cordova module. i am able to access cordova device UUID,device name and others as suggested. i have written code.
cordova.exec(getSuccess, getFailure, "DeviceDetails", "imeiNumber", []); and created class DeviceDetails but i still get failure.

Comment: "Get failure" is not helpful. What are you getting? Edit the **question**

Comment: Did you add the .java file to your project?

Comment: yes, i added the file DeviceDetails.java to the project

Comment: Please upload to Dropbox your Worklight project.

Comment: hi.. i cannot upload to dropbox.